# PL/SQL Performance Optimization - Computing Sums and Differentials from Record Changes

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, query-optimization

I have a table of items (inventory) and a table of the inventory's previous states (histories). I want to compute the amount (sums) of specific inventory (inventory.itemcode 'A' and 'B') for a specified date range, as well as its changes (differentials).

[image: Example]

I was able to do this in an Oracle PL/SQL procedure (as well as replicating it in [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/15509/1), abstracting out many things), but it is a remarkably expensive query, taking about 20 minutes on 30 days, 60000 inventory records, and 120000 history records.

From one look at the query, I can tell it is expensive - the first loop is the days, the second loop is the entire inventory, and the third loop is the entire histories for that specific inventory.

How can I make this query any faster? My guess is to use aggregate functions to reduce the amount of looping, relying on Oracle's smart SQL algorithms - But I'm not quite sure how to go about making all of this into one big query - or if that is even possible.

I am able to add new fields that may make this table better/make the computation faster, but I am unable to remove any fields.

Thanks in advance and please let me know how I can clarify or improve my question. I'm new to PL/SQL so let me know if I made any rookie mistakes.

Code:

```
procedure do
is
    start_date number;
    end_date number;
    start_date_date date;
    end_date_date date;
    currentDate varchar2(10);
    -- assoc array of itemcode[itemid]
    type code_id_table_type is table of varchar2(10) index by PLS_INTEGER;
    code_id_table code_id_table_type;
    elem varchar2(10) default ' ';  
    -- positive
    dateA number default 0;
    dateB number default 0;
    -- negative 
    dateAn number default 0;
    dateBn number default 0;
    -- running tally
    summA number default 0;
    summB number default 0;
begin
    log('DAY | sum(A B) | diff+(A B) | diff-(A B) ' || CHR(10));
    -- passed in START date and END date. these literals will be used below. 
    start_date_date := to_date('15-JUN-18', 'DD-MON-YY');
    end_date_date   := to_date('25-JUN-18', 'DD-MON-YY');
    start_date := to_number(to_char(start_date_date, 'j'));
    end_date   := to_number(to_char(end_date_date, 'j'));

    -- compute previous items 
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO summA FROM
      (
        SELECT DISTINCT t1.itemid, t1.itemcode, t1.changedate
        FROM histories t1,
        (SELECT itemid, max(changedate) as changedate
         FROM histories
         WHERE changedate < start_date_date
         GROUP BY itemid) t2
        WHERE t1.itemid = t2.itemid
        AND t1.changedate = t2.changedate
        AND t1.itemcode = 'A'
      );
      SELECT COUNT(*) INTO summB FROM
      (
        SELECT DISTINCT t1.itemid, t1.itemcode, t1.changedate
        FROM histories t1,
        (SELECT itemid, max(changedate) as changedate
         FROM histories
         WHERE changedate < start_date_date
         GROUP BY itemid) t2
        WHERE t1.itemid = t2.itemid
        AND t1.changedate = t2.changedate
        AND t1.itemcode = 'B'
      );

      -- compute a itemcode(itemid) array for all inventory as of given date
      for outerrec in (
        SELECT itemid, itemcode
        FROM inventory
      )
      loop
        for innerrec in (
          SELECT itemid, itemcode, changedate 
          FROM histories
          WHERE itemid = outerrec.itemid
          AND changedate < start_date_date
          AND ROWNUM = 1
          ORDER BY changedate DESC
        )
        loop
          code_id_table(innerrec.itemid) := innerrec.itemcode;
        end loop;
      end loop;

      -- compute differentials for every day. 
      for daterec in start_date..end_date 
      loop
        -- date iterator
        currentdate := To_char(To_date(daterec, 'j'), 'DD-MON-YY');
        -- reset counts
        dateA  := 0;
        dateB  := 0;
        dateAn := 0;
        dateBn := 0;

        for outerrec in (
          SELECT itemid, itemcode
          FROM inventory
        )
        loop
          -- get the last change of the day
          for innerrec in (
            SELECT itemid, itemcode, changedate 
            FROM histories
            WHERE itemid = outerrec.itemid
            AND changedate >= to_date(currentdate)
            AND changedate < to_date(currentdate)+1
            AND ROWNUM = 1
            ORDER BY changedate DESC
          )
          loop
            -- check existence in code table
            if (code_id_table.exists(innerrec.itemid)) then

              -- check if the code was lost that day
              if (code_id_table(innerrec.itemid) = 'A') then
                dateAn := dateAn + 1;
              elsif (code_id_table(innerrec.itemid) = 'B') then
                dateBn := dateBn + 1;
              end if;

              -- check if the code was gained that day
              if (innerrec.itemcode = 'A') then
                dateA := dateA + 1;
              elsif (innerrec.itemcode = 'B') then
                dateB := dateB + 1;
              end if;

            else
              -- new item, code is gained
              if (innerrec.itemcode = 'A') then
                dateA := dateA + 1;
              elsif (innerrec.itemcode = 'B') then
                dateB := dateB + 1;
              end if;
            end if;

            -- update code table
            code_id_table(innerrec.itemid) := innerrec.itemcode;
          end loop;
        end loop;

        -- compute sums
        summA := summA + (nvl(dateA, 0) + (0 - nvl(dateAn, 0)));
        summB := summB + (nvl(dateB, 0) + (0 - nvl(dateBn, 0)));
        -- output results
        log(To_char(To_date(currentdate), 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' (' || summA || ' ' || summB || ') (+' || dateA || ' +' || dateB || ') (-' || dateAn || ' -' || dateBn || ') ' || CHR(10));
      end loop;
```

[SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/15509/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dbms_profiler` reveals that the inner loop *("get the last change of the day")* was executed 236 times using your test data (10 inventories and 20 histories), and took most of the time. It queries `histories` one row at a time `where itemid = outerrec.itemid`, so one quick fix might be to put an index on `histories(items, changedate, itemcode)`. That's not really a substitute for a high-level restructure as all these loops are inherently resource-intensive, but I'm not really sure what it's trying to do. Some examples of the results you want would help.

This query probably doesn't do what you want:

```
SELECT itemid, itemcode, changedate
FROM histories
WHERE itemid = outerrec.itemid
AND changedate >= to_date(currentdate)
AND changedate < to_date(currentdate)+1
AND ROWNUM = 1
ORDER BY changedate DESC
```

`rownum` is generated before ordering, so you're getting one arbitrary row and then ordering that. Assuming a recent version of Oracle, that should be

```
order by changedate desc
fetch first row only
```

For older versions you can generate an ordering key using an analytic `row_number()`, and then nesting the whole thing in an inline view as you can't use an analytic function directly in an `order by` clause.

Also, `to_date(currentdate)` may just about work with your current desktop settings, but you should really use an explicit conversion format or (even better) declare `current date` as a `date` and avoid a load of type conversions.

By the way, `pkg_test.do` is a procedure, not a query, and tables have columns, not fields.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @william. I just learned how to use `dbms_profiler` and it gave me great insight into my query. I believe `innerRec` is retrieving the correct records and the results I want are being retrieved by the query - I'm running 11g. I'll make sure to apply these changes and give it a whirl Monday. Currently the index (on production system) is on `histories(itemid, changedate)` - will adding `histories(itemcode)` to the index result in a significant speed increase?

Comment: Hi @William - turns out the index makes the query slower, evidenced by Oracle choosing not to use the index... I believe this is because on the prod system, we use four different keys to map `inventory` and `histories` together.

Comment: OK. I based my comments on your SQL Fiddle where there are no indexes. Also perhaps the query above is a simplified version of the actual code. My thinking was that if you are fetching `itemid`, `itemcode`, and `changedate` based on `itemid` and `changedate`, then an index on those three columns (with `itemcode` last) will mean the query won't need to visit the table at all. If the actual situation is different, though, you'll need to tune your version of that query (that is, the query that DBMS_PROFILER tells you is being executed a zillion times).

Comment: Much thanks - I think I can figure it out from here!